# Verificação de login não inicia session

Tags: php, mysql

Possuo um sistema de login que faz a verificação de acordo com o nível de acesso do usuário que funcionava até pouco tempo mas fiz algo que parou.

Form

```
    <form class="text-center" style="padding-left: 30%; padding-right: 30%" method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
            <p class="h4 mb-4">Service Desk Embaré</p>
            <label>Usuário</label>
            <input class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="E-mail" type="text" name="usuario"><br>
            <label>Senha</label>
            <input class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="Senha" type="password" name="senha">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-block my-4" type="submit" name="submeter">Entrar</button>

<?php
    if(!empty($erros)):
        foreach ($erros as $erro):                  
            echo $erro;
        endforeach;
    endif;
?>
</form>
```

A página de login é a seguinte:

```
if (isset($_POST['submeter'])):
        $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
        $senha = $_POST['senha'];
        $erros = array();
            if(empty($usuario) or empty($senha)):
                $erros[] = "<li>Campo usuário ou senha não podem ficar em branco</li>";

            else:
                $query = "SELECT nome_login FROM usuarios WHERE nome_login = '$usuario'";
                $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);

                if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0):
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nome_login = '$usuario' AND senha = '$senha'";
                    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);

                    if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) == 1):
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nivel_acesso = 1 AND nome_login = '$usuario' AND senha = '$senha'";
                        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);

                        if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) == 1):
                            $dados = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
                            mysqli_close($conexao);
                            $_SESSION['logado'] = true;
                            $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $dados['id_usuario'];
                            header('Location: self_service/teste.php');                 
                        else:
                            header('Location: configuracoes.php');
                        endif;
                    else:
                        $erros[] = "<li>Nome de usuário ou senha incorretos</li>";
                    endif;
                else:
                    $erros[] = "<li>Nome de usuário ou senha incorretos</li>";
                endif;
            endif;
        endif;
        ?>
```

E na página self_service/teste.php, inicio da seguinte maneira:

```
// Sessão
session_start();

    <?php include 'conexao.php'; 

        // Verificação
        if(!isset($_SESSION['logado'])):
          header('Location: ../login.php');
        endif;

        // Dados
        $id = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id_usuario = '$id'";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
        $dados = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
        mysqli_close($conexao);    
    ?>
```

Acontece que na verificação, apenas o else funciona, ou seja, apenas usuários com nivel_acesso diferente de 1 conseguem logar. Usuários que possuem o nivel_acesso == 1 ficam sempre na tela de login, ao submeter o form nada acontece.

Exemplo do bd:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Estou colocando como resposta porque não possuo pontos suficientes para comentar. Qualquer coisa retiro.

Acredito que a solução seja apenas acrescentar aspas simples na busca do banco de dados, ficando assim:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nivel_acesso = '1' AND nome_login = '$usuario' AND senha = '$senha'";
```

Comment: Fiz o que sugeriu, porém não funcionou. Continua a mesma coisa, quando clica em logar e possui nivel_acesso = 1 nada acontece.

Comment: São só dois níveis de acesso? 0 e 1? O problema ocorre só com os níveis de acesso 1?

Comment: Níveis de acesso = 1 e níveis diferentes de 1. Caso eu coloque no meu bd que o usuário não é do nível 1, o acesso ocorre normalmente conforme o 'else'.

Comment: Fiz um teste colocando o print_r($dados) na página de login e retornou os valores corretamente. Acredito que o problema está dali pra frente, algo relacionado a session.